# Getting the id and values of a textbox

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery

I'm having trouble getting the id and value of the textbox.

I have this PHP code here:

```
<h1>Receive</h1>
<h1>Receive Materials</h1>

<?php
    //Materials
    $p = proj_id_from_user_id($user_id);
    $r = mysql_query("SELECT `mat_name`, `mat_id` FROM `requests` JOIN `materials` USING (`mat_id`) WHERE `stat_id`=4 AND `proj_id`='".$p."'");

    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
        $mat_id = array($rows['mat_id']);
        $mat_name = array($rows['mat_name']);

        foreach($mat_name as $mat_name_key => $materials){
            echo '<p id="receiveitem">';
            echo '<label for="mat_id">Material</label>';
            echo '<input type="text" id="'.$mat_id[$mat_name_key].'"value="'.$materials.'" disabled/>';
            echo '<label for="rec_qty">Quantity</label>';
            echo '<input type="text" id="rec_qty" />';
            echo '<input type="button" id="receive" value=Receive />';
            echo '</p>';
        }
    }
?>
```

What I want to achieve is that when I click the button receive. It will alert the values of the text box and their ids.

I also have this JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#receive').click(function(){
        alert();
    });
});
```

Comment: Just throwing random code on some else code does not make it work nor is it called programming. Instead what have you tried to find out *what exactly* is not working and *why it is not working*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#receive').click(function(){
          $('input[type=text]').each(function() {
               var input_value = $(this).val();
               var input_id = $(this).attr('id');
               alert('Value: ' + input_value + ', ID: ' + input_id);
          });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some way of identifying your textbox. If you give the textbox a CSS class of "mytextbox" then your jQuery code would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#receive').click(function(){
        alert($('input.mytextbox').val());
    });
});
```

Have a look through the [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Selectors&redirect=no) documentation.